# Sent emails table gets too large

Tags: mysql, email

I have a site which send emails and the whole sent email has been saved in mysql db table called `emails`. Now the `emails` table's size is growing really fast.

I've tried a few things to reduce the size of the table. For example I store the email's body as `gzip`ped and `base64` encoded string. But the table is now 7.5 GB and still growing really fast.

It seems not a good practice how I do it so how should I store this emails in right way? I thought about to store the gzipped body in blob but I'm afraid it won't help much.

I'd appreciate any idea how should I do it or you how solved this problem if it occurred.

Comment: Is there a problem with the size growing? I would be mindful about any data duplication you are creating too

Comment: @Takarii I had problem this big table. It slows down the mysql in some cases. If I optimize it gets better. And the backup creations is very long time too. (Of course I create backups from a replicated db)

Answer (score 1):

You should save mail content once in `email` table and manage all recipients in different table. And store your old data into mongoDB. MongoDB is best option for large data. The secondary data mange by cron, set a particular time range like 2mnth old data shift in secondary database. And when you need to use old data then connect mongoDB and retrieve data.

Go: http://www.theserverside.com/feature/How-NoSQL-MySQL-and-MogoDB-worked-together-to-solve-a-big-data-problem

http://linuxpitstop.com/migrate-mysql-to-mongodb-using-mongify-utility-linux/

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Save the mailcontent on disk and reference in your database table to the correct file. Only possible when you don't use it very often, when you want to search trough the contents it's no option, but considering the base64 encoding solution you used I don't think that's the case.

Comment: It's a good idea but in this case I should set up a different backup for this. Of course it's not a big problem. Yes I don't search in tables right now I've an index table for search.

Comment: Not a good solution. Storing to a flat file will slow everything down even more so than a large table

Answer (score 0):

We generally move sent emails to different database in sentemail table. as most of the same we don't need to refer the sent email for any search criteria. We have put the job which runs on every weekend and previous week emails get transferred to different database for archiving purpose. in current live database only one week emails have been stored and PK keeps counting how many emails have been sent since system has been started

Comment: surely that just moves the same problem to a different system?

Comment: The main db is getting cleaner it's right but I still have big tables in different db. Or you mean I should create new tables for every archive?

Comment: no big table on different db. but generally you don't need to access it if you don't use those emails again. in my case. we just send / resend the passwords so it's absolutely alright if I move them